# I cannot find the Other option to Export my Java file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, export, desktop-application

I am running on a Windows platform and I am using Eclipse for Java. I wanted to export my work to a desktop application executable file with a unique icon. However I cannot find the options in Eclipse: File > Export > ***Others*** I don't want to export it to a jar executable file. I saw Eclipse on Mas OS that there is an option. Do you think I need to install a plugin so that the "Other" will show up to the Export choices. Please let me know what to do and many thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option on the Mac is to create a Mac OS X application bundle and is only on the Mac version of Eclipse.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) question for information on creating exe files on Windows.